# Sort array of strings by two filters

Tags: java, sorting

I have the following string array:
"0 11", "22 34", "5 14", "22 13"...
How do I sort it so that both numbers are in increasing order:
"0 11", "5 14", "22 13", "22 34"?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In your example, both numbers are *not* in increasing order; for instance, 14 comes before 13.

Comment: In general, storing two informations in a String is a bad idea. Parse the strings and transform them into objects with two int properties.

Comment: Your post needs editing for clarity of expression; as it stands, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: do you need something like` "0 11", "5 14", "13 22", "22 34"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to implement an appropriate `Comparator`. Like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] ar = {"0 11", "22 34", "5 14", "22 13"};

    Arrays.sort(ar, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            String [] value1 = o1.split(" ");
            String [] value2 = o2.split(" ");
            Integer o1First = Integer.valueOf(value1[0]);
            Integer o1Second = Integer.valueOf(value1[1]);
            Integer o2First = Integer.valueOf(value2[0]);
            Integer o2Second = Integer.valueOf(value2[1]);
            if (!o1First.equals(o2First))
                return o1First.compareTo(o2First);
            return o1Second.compareTo(o2Second);

        }
    });

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` Try this,

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String[] split1 = s1.split(" ");
        String[] split2 = s2.split(" ");

        int n = split1[1].compareTo(split2[1]);

        if (n == 0) {
            return Integer.valueOf(split1[0]).compareTo(
                                  Integer.valueOf(split2[0]));
        }

        return n;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A little less verbose:

```
Arrays.sort(ar, Comparator.comparingInt((String s) -> Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[0]))
                    .thenComparingInt((String s) -> Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[1])));
```

Unfortunately Java does not currently have built in support for tuple value types. Otherwise the code could be shorter.